# Custom package error ! Missing = inserted for \ifnum

Tags: package-writing, package-options, compilation-error

I am trying to create a very basic package for use with a font called HEJI2 (which provides some music symbols to use in-line). My code looks like this:

```
\ProvidesPackage{heji}[2019/12/9 v1.0]
\RequirePackage{fontspec}[2018/07/30 vv2.6h]

\newfontfamily{\HEfont}{HEJI2.ttf}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\fsize}{\dimexpr\f@size pt\relax}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\heji}[2]{\mbox{#1\hspace{0.3mm}\raisebox{0.25\fsize}{\large\HEfont #2}}}

\DeclareOption{accfirst}{
    \renewcommand{\heji}[2]{\mbox{\raisebox{0.25\fsize}{\large\HEfont #2}#1}}
}

\ProcessOptions\relax

\endinput
```

Using the package seems to work, however when I compile it, I get the following (nonfatal) errors:

```
! Missing = insterted for \ifnum.
<to be read again>
v
1.4

?
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
v
1.4
?
```

Not sure what this means exactly. I appear to be able to return through the messages and I get a properly formatted .pdf in the end according to my package specifications. Would appreciate any help! (Compiling with Lualatex)

Comment: Replace `[2019/12/9 v1.0]` by `[2019/12/09 v1.0]`...

Comment: Thank you! Didn't even occur to me

Comment: You're welcome! Some places (for instance `texdoc usrguide`) tell that this date _should_ be in the format `YYYY/MM/DD` (which is now deprecated and should actually be in the ISO format `YYYY-MM-DD`), but it actually _must_ be in this format. I wonder if this should be made a bit more flexible...

Answer (score 2):

You can find, for example, in *LaTeX2ε for authors* (`texdoc usrguide`), section **3.2 Preamble commands**:

> [image: The optional argument <code><release-date></code> can be used to specify the earliest desired release date of the class file; it should contain a date in the format <code>yyyy/mm/dd</code>. If a version of the class older than this date is found, a warning is issued.]

That paragraph actually describes the second optional argument to `\documentclass`, but the date parser is the same. In *The LaTeX2ε sources* (`texdoc source2e`), section **68.2 Package name and version** there is more or less the same paragraph about `\ProvidesPackage`.

Firstly, that date format is (still supported but) deprecated, and now the ISO format `YYYY-MM-DD` should be used instead.

And that requirement is not entirely true. Specifically the *day* field must be `DD`, while the other two can even be empty (common sense advises not to ;-), so for example `\ProvidesPackage{heji}[1/1/09 v1.0]` would've worked. You were unfortunate enough to remove the leading zero from the wrong place ;-)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! Will try my luck with another question, which is more general. If I use fontspec to choose a system font (HEJI.ttf), is there some way I can make sure the package looks in the right directory on *anyone's* system, independent of OS etc, provided they have installed it? On windows, for instace, the files seem to be in a couple of locations...not only c:\windows\fonts, but also in some \users\local folder as well... wondering if you know anything/have any ideas on this?

Comment: @ThomasNicholson Glad it helped :-) I'm not a font expert, so I may not be the best person to help you with this. Usually, if you are writing a font package, the font files will go in the `fonts` folder of your TeX distribution's directory tree, and TeX will look for them there. If it's not for a package (by package, I mean installed by your TeX distribution), then I think it gets trickier. I suggest you mark this question as solved and ask a new one, so that someone with more experience with fonts than me can help you :-)